# get logged in username

Tags: tfs

I am trying to get the logged in user name of TFS 2013 in my custom control.

We use basic windows authentication for tfs.

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(http://YourTfsUrl:8080/tfs/Collection), new UICredentialsProvider());
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
var versionControl = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var loggedInUser = versionControl.AuthorizedUser;
```

Comment: what does "it didn't work" mean?

Comment: I was not not able to get the logged in / current user using the work item.

Comment: Why are you connecting to source control when you want the user using work items?

Comment: clarified title (tfs2913 is already in tags), removed unnecessary text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the logged in user using workitem.getPerson() in the custom control.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "tfs.AuthenticatedUse()"..